# Sqlite Singleton causing issues with Robolectric

Tags: android, android-sqlite, rx-java

I have a project setup that is pretty standard, but I'm having issues using some of my unit tests. I have RxJava for observables as I run my unit tests, and I am seeing failures with my Sqlite DB integration.

My SQLiteHelper class runs as a singleton (`getInstance()`). When I run my projects using `forkEvery = 1`, causing a new JVM to spin up for each test, everything works fine. However, as soon as I stop doing that, I start getting errors with my tests because Sqlite is busy, or locked and I see errors like this

```
com.myproject.activities.ActivityTest > testButtonClicked FAILED
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException at ActivityTest.java:477
    Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException at ActivityTest.java:477
        Caused by: com.almworks.sqlite4java.SQLiteBusyException
```

It seems like none of the changes I make, other than running a single JVM at-a-time have any affect on this. Is there a better approach to fixing this?

Comment: Are you creating different DBs for each test? Using an in memory DB? The `SQLiteDatabase` class is not thread safe. You can test if this is your problem by creating a unique DB for each test (which is probably correct anyway since it ensures each test runs independent of others).

Comment: What is the best way to create a new unique database for each test? Literally just copy/paste/reference the database file in the setup/@Before method?

Comment: If you are using an on-disk DB, you could just create a unique DB file per test (`File.createTempFile`) or use an in-memory DB. Or run your tests serially and zero out the DB in your setup.